# jquery .load path trouble

Tags: jquery, path

On my site I use the .load to pull in content from another page.  It works only in certain situations though.  when the site url is entered as http://www.klossal.com/portfolio  the .load content only works when entered this way:

```
.load('/space_fullscreen.html');
```

or this way:
    .load('www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');

The problem is sometimes people will type a url in as http://klossal.com/portfolio and when they do this the previous two paths no longer work, I have to go in and change it to:

```
.load('http://klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
```

is there a way of setting it up so it will work regardless of how people type in the url?

The entire script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#fullscreen_launch").click(function(){
$('#fullscreen').empty();
$("#fullscreen").animate({
top: '0px',
height:'100%',
}, 950, function() {
$('#fullscreen')
   .load('.../space_fullscreen.html');
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see that you're using the actual input of the user to determine what page to load. Can you explain this part: "The problem is sometimes people will type a url in as http://klossal.com/portfolio and when they do this the previous two paths no longer work, I have to go in and change it to:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the full url on `.load` and then browser same-origin policy blocks the request. For browser "www.klossal.com" is not the same as "klossal.com".

2 ways to solve this problem:

1) The easiest and good way: Use only relative urls. Call `.load('space_fullscreen.html')` instead of `.load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html')`, so the browser will make the request to the same origin (with or without www) and the same-origin policy will not block the request.

Or

2) Configure your application to redirect from "klossal.com" to "www.klossal.com".

Comment: so even when I do .load('space_fullscreen.html') and type in the url as klossal.com/portfolio or http://klossal.com/portfolio it doesn't load anything.  It has to have a www in front for some reason.

Comment: Open javascript console and type: ` $('#fullscreen').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');` and see the message: same-origin policy blabla...

Comment: Then type ` $('#fullscreen').load('space_fullscreen.html');` and see that the error is gone. You have another errors on that page. But i'm tell that what you've asked are solved. Your problem on loading that document is the same-origin policy.

Comment: Tip: your pages are HUGE: 6.45mb for a page is too much.

Comment: yea, I think it's just large images?  I'll go back in when it's all done an resize some things.  So it brings up the page, but it's weird, klossal.com/portfolio loads the image but the slider is broken, www.klossal.com/portfolio the slider works.  If you go to the page and scroll down and click on fullscreen right above "A Little Bit of Info" you'll see.  Thanks so much for helping me with this.

Comment: the problem is royalSlider plugin. try to remove the www... from the script tags: <script src="http://www.klossal.com/js/royalslider/demo/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Remove all your absolute paths and try, 'til there you'll never know if it works.

Comment: bam!  thank you very much sir!  really appreciate you helping me with that.

Comment: site size do to just large images right?  is there a fast way to figure that out?

Comment: Yes, the images are very large. The home page size is 2.45mb, on these 2.31mb are images. Compact images (or reduce the image sizes).